# How do I tell which is the visible window if there are multiple similar windows

Tags: gnome-shell, window, ubuntu-dock, minimize

I opened 4 terminals, 3 are visible, the other is minimized.

[image]

I want to restore the minimized window, i.e. have the 4 windows visible.

I click the terminal icon, it shows 4 previews. Which preview should I click to restore the minimized window?

Anyway, my goal is to restore the minimized window. If there are better ways, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the GNOME shell extension [**Window List**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/). It displays a list of windows at the bottom of the screen and also greys out minimised windows.

For example in the screenshot below there are four Nautilus windows open, with first two being minimised.
[image]
(note that it also puts square brackets around the minimised window title)

Refer to this for installing and managing GNOME extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)

Comment: I think it will work. I will try later, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As you can clearly see, the bottom right terminal window is the one in use. Just click on the left one and it will be displayed at the same size alongside the current one.

Comment: How can you clearly see that? Are you comparing the two images? I'm not good at comparing images, Are there any other ways?

Comment: I used another example. I want to restore the minimized windows among the 4 similar windows. I don't know how to do that easily

Comment: Unfortunately you now have 4 windows, 3 of which are identical so you can't immediately tell them apart. In a normal situation each window would have different info. However if you click on each of the 2 identical non-minimised ones the scroll bar on the minimised active window becomes highlighted. So in this case the one that fails to highlight is the one to restore